# Symfony2 from Windows(WAMP) => to MAC(MAMP)

Tags: php, mysql, windows, macos, symfony

**I maked a Symfony2 project under Windows ( WAMP ) and I want the try it in MAC ( MAMP ) ...!
this is the file parameters.yml under Windows :**

```
parameters:

    database_host: 127.0.0.1

    database_port: null

    database_name: portailwebensa

    database_user: root

    database_password: null

    mailer_transport: smtp

    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1

    mailer_user: null

    mailer_password: null
```

**I change these parameters so that they matches at the MAC , but I get the following error:**

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ensa/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ensa/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(40): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ensa/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(41): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ensa/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(356): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', NULL, Array) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ensa/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(613): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ensa/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/SingleTablePersister.php(158): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->quote('professeur') #5 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ensa/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 93

**Thank you in advance I count on you :)**

Answer (score 0):

Mac enables socket connexion by default, so you could try to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 under database_host parameter